# PRAGMA cache_spill and WAL

Tags: sqlite

1. Does `PRAGMA cache_spill` have any effect in WAL mode?
2. Assume `PRAGMA cache_spill=TRUE`. Before `PRAGMA cache_size` is full, in what situations would sqlite choose to modify the DB (i.e. exclusive lock), instead of spilling cache to temporary files (no need for exclusive locking of DB)? In other words, I don't see in what situation cache spilling could lock the DB. At the same time I often see sqlite making temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

> Does PRAGMA cache_spill have any effect in WAL mode?

I believe that it does. Basically you can assume that the WAL file is part of the database file.

> In other words, I don't see in what situation cache spilling could lock the DB.

I believe the *"dirty page"* is a changed page and thus written, in the case of the cache_spill, to the database file (albeit the WAL file) and thus the need to lock the database/file (and hence the WAL file) to protect against other writes (more so than when using Journal mode if I understand *"Disk I/O operations tends to be more sequential using WAL."* correctly. https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html ).